# calling context.lookup("myJndiBeanName") returns instance of bean?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jndi, jboss6.x, jta

Quick question about EJB 3 stateless bean jndi lookup from context.  Does `context.lookup("myBean")` return an instance of the bean? My bean is not a singleton.

The reason that I ask is because I keep getting transaction time outs on JBoss AS 6 for my persistence CRUD service on inserts and deletes.  I have a Callable in which I inject a persistence CRUD stateless bean so that it does only 5,000 inserts in its own transaction (hence the question about returning a new instance and not the same instance for each call).  In the `Callable.call()` method, I inject the stateless beans with `context.lookup("myBean")` since I have about 20 Callables passed to an `ExecutorService.submit(Callable<T>)`.

Bottom line is I do not understand why it times out at the end of the process (all data is successfully inserted: 600,000 inserts) but at the end of the job, the timeout error is thrown by JBoss.

Stack trace, "caused by" error:

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA-16063 The transaction is not active!
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1148) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:119) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:82) [:0.0.1]
        ... 70 more
```

Full stack trace:

```
    14:40:14,609 SEVERE [context] javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transactio
 rolled back
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:178) [:2.0.3-]
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:84) [:2.0.3-]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:773) [:2.0.3-]
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:296) [:2.0.3-]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781) [:2.0.3-]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246) [:2.0.3-]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77) [:2.0.3-]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97) [:2.0.3-]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114) [:2.0.3-]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308) [:2.0.3-]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:115) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:87) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:255) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) [:1.0.3]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:182) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67) [:1.0.1]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:323) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:380) [:1.7.17]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor335.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_20]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler$LocalContainerInvocation.invokeTarget(SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler.java:184) [:1.0.11]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousClientInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousClientInterceptor.java:143) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler$LocalInvokableContextHandler.invoke(SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler.java:159) [:1.0.11]
        at $Proxy217.invoke(Unknown Source)     at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:185) [:1.0.11]
        at $Proxy220.runEngine(Unknown Source)  at com.ls.forecast.web.beans.ExpectedReturnEngineBean.runEngine(ExpectedReturnEngineBean.java:20) [:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_20]
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:196) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149) [:2.0.3-]
        ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA-16063 The transaction is not active!
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1148) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:119) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:82) [:0.0.1]
        ... 70 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee for Stateless session beans that you always get the same instance. Those beans are most often pooled and the container will just use any bean from the pool.

600k inserts distributed in 5k batches would when they run in parallel create 120 slsb that all try to access the database in parallel, all trying to get a lock etc. I guess that you "simply" run into a situation where the parallel task block each other out enough for the whole set of transactions timing out and being rolled back.

You may post your code, as so far this ends up in reading the cyrstal ball.

Comment: Is there any way to set the pool?  I actually want to get unique beans when I inject them with JNDI look ups.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my design was not in line with EJB specification, where you should not use multithreading unless using the EJB API. I rewrote my classes so that the multithreaded code is within an EJB and uses the annotation @Asynchronous.  No more threading related code (ExecutorService, Callable, etc...).